# When is the best time of year to transplant established strawberries?

Tags: transplanting, strawberries

I've got a 4 foot by 8 foot bed of `Mara des Bois` strawberries that's been growing for about 4 years now. Due to excessive heat the last two years about half the plants have died. I would like to dig up the remaining plants and move them to a better spot in the garden. Would it be better to do this in the fall or spring?

Since I'll be moving the plants and will be able to amend the soil is there anything in particular that I should add for them or is compost/composted manure good enough?

Comment: +1 from me. I am thinking of doing the same in the fall, but I wonder what to put in the future bed and whether raised beds are good idea for strawberries

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I usually move mine in the spring, but have moved them in the early fall with good results. If you live in a cold climate, be sure to move them early enough so they can get established before the ground freezes. I generally just use compost and composted manure, but others may have better advice on ammendments.